Retrieving the content of the file of remote host which is not part of ansible playbook command, how to achieve this
I am exploring the use of Ansible module called slurp in my playbook. Just curious to know if it works in this particular scenario here:
Situation: Joining a new rke2 agent node to the already running rke2 cluster.
I am running a playbook on a particular node (let say agent-node3) using ansible-playbook join-cluster.yml -i hosts.ini --limit 'agent-node3' to join the existing running cluster. my hosts.ini has below inventory contents:
[rke2-servers]
rke2-server1
rke2-server2

[rke2-node-agents]
agent-node1
agent-node2
agent-node3

main.yml
---
- name: Server play
  hosts: rke2-servers
  become: true
  roles:
  - rke2-servers
- name: rke2 agent play
  hosts: rke2-agent
  become: true
  roles:
  - rke2-node-agents
---

Roles sturcture:
rke2-servers
rke2-node-agent




I do not want to run this playbook on other nodes (`agent-node1`, `agent-node2`) as there are already part of this cluster, only need to run on `agent-node3`.

To join the cluster, `agent-node3` need to retrieve the token from another server (`rke2-server1`) which is not part of above playbook command (`ansible-playbook join-cluster.yml -i hosts.ini --limit 'agent-node3'`) and save it in a variable then wondering what is the best way to achieve this?

I looked at `slurp `module, it feels like it only works on hosts which are passed via playbook. 

I have not tried to use any `slurp` or `command` or `shell` module to retrieve the content of the remote host and I am expecting that what is the best way to achieve this


How does an agent know which server to retrieve the token from?

Are you using a specific module that is used to join the node to the cluster?  If so, wouldn't it be idempotent?  If the server is already joined the module that joins the node to the cluster would not run for that node and just display OK instead of changed.

@Squashman, thanks for replying, I think you misunderstood the question. I am trying to join the rke2-agent node to the existing cluster, to do that I need to get the node token from rke2-server which is rke2-server1. here I am asking if i use the above given module to retrieve the token from rke2-server1, would it work even though I am not passing rke2-server hostname in the ansible-playbook commandline

@VladimirBotka, that is what I am asking here: As I am not passing rke2-server hostname in the ansible-playbook command line. how do I pass the rke2-server hostname so that agent-node can retrieve the node token

How does the play know which agent shall retrieve the node token from rke2-server? This question does not depend on how you tell the play about rke2-server.

I completely understand the question.  My comment still stands. Regardless without seeing what modules you are using in your playbook, I don't think anyone can give you a solid answer.

I am passing the agent via (ansible-playbook join-cluster.yml -i hosts.ini --limit 'agent-node3'), I have different roles define for different hosts so question is how can I retrieve the token from rke2-server without passing in the playbook commandline. As far as I know I can define specific hosts on task level under roles. If I pass rke-server via commandline then roles associated with those rke-servers will kicked off and they will get provisioned again which I donot want.  I have given my inventory and main yml file and roles in the original request @VladimirBotka
